# Accept calls from my iPhone 4S on my Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, iphone, bluetooth

What steps would be necessary to connect an iPhone 4S to a Windows 7 desktop computer, and then to accept a phone call from the microphone/headset on my computer?  I'm essentially looking to pair my iPhone to my computer in the same manner in which it has been paired with my automobile.

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of it already, but why not Skype? Edit: Ohhh, I think get it now. You want to be able to accept the call through your phone, but on the computer?

Comment: That's correct, I'd like to accept a call through my computer so I don't have to buy a separate bluetooth headset.

Comment: I haven't watched it all, but just found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2_Q_m7hGxs

Answer (score -1):

I'm just throwing this idea out there, it is probably flawed in some way, haha.

If you bought the [following or something like it](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00102ZN40), I think you could run a stereo mini cable from the pc to an adapter that splits it into 2 RCA cables (amazon has the cables in a package deal with the mixer). Plug that into the mixer. Do the same thing from the iphone's headphone jack.

Grab the headphone adapter and listen directly to the mixer. You now will have sepperate volume controls for the device right there in front of you! Is that kind of what you're wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I understand there may be other options, and the risk of sounding difficult or stubborn, I'm really just looking to use the equipment I have to accomplish the goal.  I feel the hardware is there, I'm just not sure if it was possible in the software.

Comment: No not difficult or stubborn. Sometimes that's where the best ideas originate! I personally don't know if the capability is in the software. The only experience I have is with soft phone software allowing you to make and take calls via your cell phone connected to your pc. If I come across anything I'll post back here.